# Increase margins in a pdf file (not using custom scaling)

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I've got a few pages of a pdf that will be holepunched, hence my need to increase the margins.

I've already looked at this thread: [Increase PDF margins by reducing size of content (without changing overall page size)](https://superuser.com/questions/918287/increase-pdf-margins-by-reducing-size-of-content-without-changing-overall-page)
but I don't wish to use custom scaling factors as I will need to combine this pdf with other pdf files (which also have different size-margins).

I'm using Adobe Pro DC although I won't mind installing any additional software

Comment: Are you software shopping here or looking for a solution with Adobe specifically? I assume you're saying either would be fine, correct?

Comment: Do you also have as a requirement not changing the overall page size?

Comment: I don't mind using any software and I'd like to keep my page size A4

Comment: You don't want to scale the page contents at all (eg: achieve margins by shifting contents to the right) ? Or you want to scale page contents but specify the margins in inches and have the scaling factor be auto-computed (eg: get same margin size for all pages)?

Comment: I'd like the content to be uniformly scaled down, so the margins as the same for all pages

Comment: Decrease the font size, leading or tracking?

Comment: Well, sorry for not making this clear earlier, the document I'm trying to edit is music manuscript, so I'm trying to treat each page as an image